# Creating a twitter bootstrap split button radio group

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Given the code below.  How can I create each options button as part of the same button radio group?

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="plan-option span3 well">
        <h3 class="plan-option-title">Product Name</h3>
        <div class="plan-pricing">
            <p class="plan-price">$x<span class="small"> one-time</span></p>
            <div class="signup-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn-large btn-block btn" >select</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="plan-option span3 well">
        <h3 class="plan-option-title">Product Name</h3>
        <div class="plan-pricing">
            <p class="plan-price">$x<span class="small"> one-time</span></p>
            <div class="signup-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn-large btn-block btn" >select</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="plan-option span3 well">
        <h3 class="plan-option-title">Product Name</h3>
        <div class="plan-pricing">
            <p class="plan-price">$x<span class="small"> one-time</span></p>
            <div class="signup-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn-large btn-block btn" >select</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="plan-option span3 well">
        <h3 class="plan-option-title">Product Name</h3>
        <div class="plan-pricing">
            <p class="plan-price">$x<span class="small"> one-time</span></p>
            <div class="signup-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn-large btn-block btn" >select</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have tried wrapping everything in a btn-group div but that does not work.  I have also tried adding data-toggle="buttons-radio" to each button but that does not work.

The goal is to have a selector button for the plans where only one of the buttons is active.  Does this have to be done with custom jquery or can this be done via the button groups and buttons-radio from twitter bootstrap?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz as my post says, I have tried putting it in a button group but did not work... This is the base code provided.  And yes they are split up in different wells.

Comment: "... each options button ... radio group". It's hard to form a group of radio buttons when there are none.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Each button is part of the radio group.  I only want one of the buttons to be active at a time and thought I could use the buttons-radio data-toggle that Twitter Bootstrap offers

Comment: Ah, I see. I won't try to provide an answer as there's at least one good one below already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is just use JQuery and add class ".active" to the button that you clicked,  then check which one of those has ".active" class onSubmit.

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTeU3/3/)

Comment: While @16dots answer is spot on, in terms of UX, I would think twice about implementing this kind of UI as it can be very confusing for users who may not see other items being unselected when they select another item.

Comment: @16dots this is what I thought I would have to do.  The layout is basically a price table where the user is presented with all options for a plan to the site.  they click on the choice they want and then all others are unselected.  Thank you for confirming this is what I need to do

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is include bootstrap-button.js from [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js) and it should take care of the rest.

Please find the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/JqEkD/)

**EDIT** : For this particular case, the text near the btn-group disappears as bootstrap sets font-size to 0px inside a btn group. If text is required to be placed inside a btn-group, a label can be used instead.

DEMO updated

I hope this helps

Comment: That almost works however the price gets removed when doing this.. Any idea why?

Comment: Bootstrap attaches a font-size:0 at line 3438 of its source and hence the <p> tag is not visible. Using a label(instead of p) in that place should do it or manually setting the font.

Comment: Though this seemed to work at the start... It was not fully reliable for my case.